# How to close boost thread on application closure?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using thread

```
hThreadat = CreateThread(NULL,0,MyFunc,&m_ThreadVec,0,&ThreadIDat);
```

and code for MyFunc

```
    DWORD WINAPI  MYFunc(LPVOID temp)
{
//some code
boost::thread u(&faceThread);
u.interrupt();  
return 0;
// new code end}
```

Problem is= When I close the application all hThreadat threads terminates but boost thread don't. It cause error. How do I close that boost thread when i close the application.
Actually boost thread is cascaded within windows threads. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think `interrupt` is what you're looking for. Typically you'll want to set a variable which causes the function `faceThread` to exit. You would probably then call `u.join()` which will wait until `faceThread` has exited, and then exit the program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437395/how-can-i-execute-two-threads-asynchronously-using-boost/12437526#12437526